# Motor coupling connection

Tags: motors, torque

I choose an AC motor (IEC) with frame number 71. The key on the shaft of the motor is $5mm,$, $4.23 mm$ and $6 mm$ in diameter. At other hand i cant't find a safety coupling (torque limiter) with exactly the same dimensions as the key way on the  motor. They are all a bit smaller or bigger but they have the same  diameter as the motor. for instance $4 mm$, $2.23 mm$ and $6 mm$ in diameter.

what can i do ? Is it possible to use a slightly greater safety coupling or the dimensions of the both, should exactly be the same ?

[image]

Comment: A diagram would help, what is the shaft diameter? And woodruff keys are usually rectangular...

Comment: @SolarMike i try to update the question by providing photos. The shaft of the motor is 12 mm

Comment: Did you notice the R6 measurement means radius of 6mm, 12 mm diameter. This will change your search options.

Comment: @fred_dot_u , i know, but as i stated, that rectangular sections causes me troubles, i can't find any safety coupling with exactly the same dimensions as this rectangular  section

Comment: As solar mike suggests, woodruff keys are rectangular. The drawing you've provided suggests that the proper key size is as dimensioned. I expect that you'll find a slot in the motor shaft to accept a key to mate with your coupling. One then cuts the key to fit as required. Do you know if the shaft has the keyway cut and provides a key? More product information would be useful (links?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This extract from a [Baldor IE Chart](http://www.electricmotorservice.net/iechart.pdf) may help.

[image]

*Figure 1. The Frame 71 keyway dimensions are highlighted.*

As everyone else has pointed out, keyways and keys are rectangular so we can't figure out where all your diameters are coming from.

Your drawing is a little strange as it seems to have a shaft entry with keyway rather than a protruding shaft.

> Is it possible to use a slightly greater safety coupling or the dimensions of the both, should exactly be the same?

The keyway should be a snug fit. Any play or slop will result in backlash during starting and stopping and this will chew up the key or shaft or both.

Answer (score 0):

Once you find a coupling that fits the shaft diameter and the other constraints such as size etc, then all you need to do is to get a machine shop to cut a matching keyway to match the one in the motor shaft.

They will also machine a key to match f necessary. This is a small easy job...